# Event type of shown.bs.modal calling 2 times

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please check my code:

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Teste</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Teste modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
        <input id="input-1a" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  alert("alert");
})
```

I'm using this plugin: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#usage

Here it is in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30285/

In line `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e)`, it does 2 times.

Removing line `<input id="input-1a" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false">`, works correctly.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using two JavaScript libraries that can run into conflicts with jQuery. In order to avoid these conflicts, you need to put jQuery in no-conflict mode as following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
       alert("alert");
       e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Yeah, try adding the following to your jQuery code: e.stopPropagation();

Comment: What is `e.stopPropagation();` ?

Comment: stopPropagation stops the event from bubbling up the event chain. More details at https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 1):

I get the same trouble, and this is my solution

```js
var tm = false;
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
if(tm) {tm=false;return;}
else { alert('ok'); tm= true;}
})
```